# Intuition for definition of terminating renewal process

Tags: stochastic-processes

When the interarrival distribution F of an associated renewal process happens to have $F(\infty)<1$ (I'm assuming this to be the limit), we have a terminating renewal process.

Why this name? what's the intuition for it?